# Tensorflow's seq2seq: tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp, embedding

I am following quite closely the Seq2seq for translation tutorial here https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/tutorials/networks_seq2seq_nmt#define_the_optimizer_and_the_loss_function while testing on other data. I meet an error when instantiating the Encoder which is defined as

```
class Encoder(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_dim, enc_units, batch_sz):
    super(Encoder, self).__init__()
    self.batch_sz = batch_sz
    self.enc_units = enc_units
    self.embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)

    ##-------- LSTM layer in Encoder ------- ##
    self.lstm_layer = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(self.enc_units,
                                   return_sequences=True,
                                   return_state=True,
                                   recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform')

  def call(self, x, hidden):
    x = self.embedding(x)
    output, h, c = self.lstm_layer(x, initial_state = hidden)
    return output, h, c

  def initialize_hidden_state(self):
    return [tf.zeros((self.batch_sz, self.enc_units)), tf.zeros((self.batch_sz, self.enc_units))]
```

It is falling when testing here

```
# Test Encoder Stack
encoder = Encoder(vocab_size, embedding_dim, units, BATCH_SIZE)

# sample input
sample_hidden = encoder.initialize_hidden_state()
sample_output, sample_h, sample_c = encoder(example_input_batch, sample_hidden)
```

The error is the following

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Seq2seq/Seq2seq-V3.py", line 132, in <module>
    sample_output, sample_h, sample_c = encoder(example_input_batch, sample_hidden)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:/Users/Seq2seq/Seq2seq-V3.py", line 119, in call
    x = self.embedding(x)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Exception encountered when calling layer "embedding" (type Embedding).

indices[12,148] = 106 is not in [0, 106) [Op:ResourceGather]

Call arguments received:
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(64, 200), dtype=int64)
```

TF 2.0

This might be a problem in TF Addons, would you have some experience with that?

EDIT

the tutorial tokenizes at the word level : I encode the text at the char level and 106 is my `vocab_size` (number of characters)

Answer (score 1):

This is enough of a hint in fact

```
indices[12,148] = 106 is not in [0, 106) [Op:ResourceGather]
```

I had to make sure my vocabulary is `vocab_size = len(vocab)+1`. The dataset construction now goes

```
text = open(FILE_PATH, 'rb').read().decode(encoding='utf-8') 
vocab = sorted(set(text))

# [...]

vocab_size = len(vocab)+1
```

Answer (score 0):

vocabulary size should be always :  len(vocab)+1